# Can I load jar dynamically in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, jar

I have one JAVA program to run groovy script.

Example:
`String returnMessage = new GroovyScriptEngine(".").run("hello.groovy", binding);`

I want to use jar which added at runtime by the user from my application(e.g. jdbc.jar), so that users do not need to know where it is. 
How can I load jar? so that I can use classes defined under this jar only into the `hello.groovy`.

hello.groovy contains:
`println "Hello Groovy!"
// code of access the class of jdbc.jar
SomeClass someObj = new SomeClass();`

Answer (score 0):

You can load a jar at runtime by using `@Grapes` dependency management meta-data.
Add a grapes block to the top of your hello.groovy like shown below. The dependency will be downloaded from maven at run time. The block below is using Oracles odbc jdbc library, but you should be able to find your own on Maven Central. Search for your library on Maven Central and there will be a 'Grapes' tab for that version where you can copy a block similar to this:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='com.oracle', module='ojdbc14', version='10.2.0.4.0')
)
```